# How to take this kind of a STDIN inputs in c++?

Tags: c++, user-input, stdin

In lots of hackathon they provide testcases. So in those test cases they provide inputs in different ways through STDIN. This is one of the situation I struggle at all.

This is one kind of a input: (This is one testcase)

```
Mike
John
Ahmed
Sangha
Daniel
Ann
```

So here I have 6 inputs. But they don't provide number of inputs. So I can't use `for loop` or `while loop` to take this input. Because I don't know how many iteration I should do. So I have to take inputs until end. But this is not a input from a file. So I can't use `EOF` as well. This input is from STDIN. So how can I take this kind of input and store it in an array? Also I don't know how many elements should create in array. Because I don't know how many number of inputs are there. (different testcases may contain different number of inputs). How can I solve this kind of a problem?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: A while loop using `fgets()` for C or `std::getline()` for C++.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller problems. Why must it be an array, and not some other container? A linked list would solve this problem, and it is something every programmer should know how to create. If you knew the number of elements at compile time, could you solve the whole problem? What if you knew it at run time before the input? Do you know how to enlarge an array?

Comment: Why both C and C++? Please don't make us do extra work. Focus on *one* language at a time. These languages have *completely* different approaches to this problem. It's worth noting C++ will require less code but more learning.

Comment: @Beta Yeah it may be a linked list as well. I just used array to say that I don't have number of inputs. My problem was how to take this kind of input. I wanted a way to read this input until end. So then I can use linked list or array or tree... create nodes and insert each line at a time. But the problem was how to take this input . Thanks

Comment: @Shawn I'll check out  `fgets()` and `std::getline()`. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman I'll change it to c++. Thanks about informing.

Comment: With C++ you have tools like `std::string` which can be used in conjunction with `std::vector` or `std::list`, whereas in C you get *nothing*. You must pretty much make your own everything

Comment: In C++ your input stream will fail an `if` check if you hit the end of stream. You can basically do `while (input)` and read in with `getline()`. Combine that with `push_back` into a `std::vector` and you're almost done.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use EOF, because stdin *is* a file (at least on linux)

Answer (score 1):

The input here clearly shows you how many entries are presented. Note that each entry is on a newline so, considering it as a delimiter, you can parse your input stream and get the entries separated and also get the count of entries.

C++ getline() does this exactly:

istream& getline( istream& is, string& str, char delim );

Last param to getline is optional because it uses '\n' as default.

If you want to do it the raw way, you could setup a file pointer and do a lookahead for '\n' and read everything before it into new item of a variable array(vector) ...do this repeatedly until u reach EOF of stream(or filestream)